# JavaScript equivalent RegExp for PHP

Tags: javascript, php

Im looking for JavaScript equivalent RegExp for PHP.

This PHP RegExp class must have same methods with same returns as JavaScript version.

I can not find anything.

Thanks

[EDIT]

I need same class in PHP as is in JavaScript. preg_match methods in php has different results as RegExp.exec in JavaScript. And also has different flags

Comment: You could write a PHP class to work in the same way as the JavaScript class - it would use the `preg_*` methods internally.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Javascript `RegExp` object in order to accomplish what you want.

Here's an example taken from MDN:

```
var re = /(\w+)\s(\w+)/;
var str = 'John Smith';
var newstr = str.replace(re, '$2, $1');
console.log(newstr);
```

You can check more of them [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp).

Comment: no,no . I need javascript RegExp inside PHP. not php inside javascript

Comment: This is not PHP inside JavaScript, this is a pure JavaScript implementation.

Answer (score -2):

I really don't believe you searched all that hard.  Top google result for "PHP RegEx": http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Comment: I need same class as is in javascript. not function. and this function has diferent result as regex in javascript. and diferent flags

Comment: Well, you can't really ask for that.  Different languages solve problems in different ways.  preg_match does evaluate regex, so I would suggest trying to learn it.  While it does take it's inputs in a different order, the functionality is still the same;  it evaluates regex.